# Most efficient approach to insert in a 1-many tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a database with 2 tables in a one-to-many relationship. Here's a hypothetical scenario:

```
animals
- animal_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
- animal_name VARCHAR(30)

sightings
- sigh_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
- sigh_animalid INTEGER
- sigh_datetime DATETIME
```

What is the most efficient approach to check if an animal already exists in the 'animals' table, if it doesn't exist insert it, obtain the ID and insert a record into the 'sightings' table? Thanks!

Comment: you can write a stored procedure for that but that will never be performant, sql is not a "normal" programming language, so your idea should be implemented in another language

Comment: _"I need high performance because this process should occur every 3 or 4 seconds."_ - that's not close to what many of us would consider "high performance" - high-perf would be like _millions of inserts_ per second. A single MySQL INSERT into a table without too many `INDEX` objects (and without any triggers and with a reasonable amount of (fully indexed) FKs) shouldn't take more than ~5ms on a server using spinning-rust disks, and less than 1ms with an SSD in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Give `animals` a unique index on the `animal_name` column to prevent duplicates. Then use `INSERT IGNORE` to insert into the `animals` table if it doesn't already exist.

Then use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to get the ID from the `animals` table when inserting into `sightings`.

```
ALTER TABLE animals ADD UNIQUE INDEX (animal_name); -- do this just once

-- to add a new animal sighting
INSERT IGNORE INTO animals (animal_name) VALUES ('giraffe');

INSERT INTO sightings (sigh_animalid, sigh_datetime)
SELECT animal_id, NOW()
FROM animals
WHERE animal_name = 'giraffe';
```

Comment: That has an annoying problem -- When 'giraffe' is already in the table the `INSERT IGNORE` will bump the auto_inc id before realizing that it is already there.  This can lead to an overflow in the `INT` column.

Comment: The technique in [_Normalization_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization) avoids burning an `id`.  However, it is clumsy for a single animal; it is designed for, say, a hundred inserts per second.